# 'System.Threading.CancellationToken'...is not marked as serializable

Tags: c#, serialization, accord.net, cancellation-token

I am using Accord.NET to create and save a `StepwiseLogisticRegressionModel`. When I try to serialize and save the model, I am getting the following error:

> Type 'System.Threading.CancellationToken' in Assembly 'mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' is not marked as serializable.

Saving other models such as NaiveBayes seems to work fine.

Here is the code that I have tried:

```
StepwiseLogisticRegressionAnalysis model;
string file = Path.Combine(path, filename);
Serializer.Save(obj: model, path: file);
```

and

```
StepwiseLogisticRegressionAnalysis model;
string file = Path.Combine(path, filename);
using(FileStream stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create))
{
    var binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
    binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, best);
}
```

How do I resolve this?

---

Edit: Here is a working example:

```
double[][] inputs =
{
    //            Age  Smoking
    new double[] { 55,    0   },  // 1
    new double[] { 28,    0   },  // 2
    new double[] { 65,    1   },  // 3
    new double[] { 46,    0   },  // 4
    new double[] { 86,    1   },  // 5
    new double[] { 56,    1   },  // 6
    new double[] { 85,    0   },  // 7
    new double[] { 33,    0   },  // 8
    new double[] { 21,    1   },  // 9
    new double[] { 42,    1   },  // 10
    new double[] { 33,    0   },  // 11
    new double[] { 20,    1   },  // 12
    new double[] { 43,    1   },  // 13
    new double[] { 31,    1   },  // 14
    new double[] { 22,    1   },  // 15
    new double[] { 43,    1   },  // 16
    new double[] { 46,    0   },  // 17
    new double[] { 86,    1   },  // 18
    new double[] { 56,    1   },  // 19
    new double[] { 55,    0   },  // 20
};

double[] output =
{
    0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0
};

var regression = new StepwiseLogisticRegressionAnalysis(inputs, output,
    new[] { "Age", "Smoking" }, "Cancer");

regression.Learn(inputs, output); 

var path = $@"C:\";
var filename = "StepWiseRegressionModel.accord";
string file = Path.Combine(path, filename);
Serializer.Save(regression, file);
```

Comment: In the first code block you're using `model` before initializing its value, and in the second code block you're not even using `model`. I don't see any indication of `CancellationToken` in your posted code. Can you post a [mre]?

Comment: @gunr2171 I just added a working example.

Comment: The class is marked serializable, but the token within the class isn't serializable. Maybe it's an oversight. If it's meant to be serialized then that one property should be decorated with `NonSerialized`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there's a private field somewhere in `StepwiseLogisticRegressionAnalysis` (or a subobject) that contains a `CancellationToken`, which can't be serialized.

You should try serializing the output model of the analysis (see the `regression.Current.Regression` property).

Just keep in mind that binary serialization of an object is fairly fragile, unless it's specifically supported. The deserialization environment has to be the exact same as the serialization (same library versions, C# versions, OS version, etc). Serializing the data, then reconstructing the object from it would be better if possible.

Comment: That was it! I had been busting my head trying to figure out how I was going to serialize that field, but it never occurred to me to simply save the object I needed.